# Where is the API documentation for Apex InboundEmail?

Tags: apex, email, api

I want to know all the API's in

```
Messaging.InboundEnvelope
```

and

```
Messaging.InboundEmail
```

I google and all I get is tutorials. I want the API's.

I want to see if I can get the sent date of the email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The InboundEmail documentation is [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_email_inbound.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_email_inbound.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp). Sent date will be in the `headers` field, defined as 'a list of the RFC 2822 headers in the email, including: received from, custom headers, message-ID, date'.